# Tuple that I append to a .txt file will not save to file

Tags: python, file, text

So I am making an atm program that keeps a record of deposits, withdrawals, and balance. Here is my deposit function

```
def deposite(bal):
    d=input("How much would you like to deposite? ")
    newbal = float(bal) + float(d)
    write = "deposit ", str(d), str(newbal)
    print(write)
    f1 = open('atmrecord', 'a')
    f1.write(str(write) + '\n')
    print(f1.closed)
    f1.close()
    print("Your new balance is", newbal)
    return newbal
```

'write' is a tuple I know but I can't for the life of me figure out why it will not save to the .txt file. Earlier in my code I am able to read the file for getting the balance and I thought I had my write command right but it won't save. The code runs fine without any errors and it appears it closes the file when its done but when I open my .txt after running there is never the extra line of data. Any thoughts/tips would be appreciated.
Also 'write' = ('deposit ', '1', '10001.0') if d=1 for example

Comment: Well, this looks like it *should* append to your file, however, almost certainly, `" ".join(str(write))` is not what you want.

Comment: Are you sure it’s not a matter of file names? You mention .txt, but your code doesn’t.

Comment: I ran your code and it worked. Did you call `deposite()`?

Comment: Wow i feel stupid it was file names @Piotr

Comment: now wondering why '/n' hasn't put 'write' on a new line below existing ones

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to call `str` on `write` because it will return something like `('deposit ', '10', '20.0')`. Simply do:

```
def deposite(bal):
    d = input("How much would you like to deposite? ")
    newbal = float(bal) + float(d)
    write = "deposit ", str(d), str(newbal)
    print(write)

    with open('atmrecord', 'a') as f:
        f.write(" ".join(write) + '\n')

    print("Your new balance is", newbal)
    return newbal
```

Comment: I see your point. I changed write to a list then had to call it str(). Then I just use the index to remove the not int indices when I use the balance again later